# Getting Error System.HttpResponse[Status=Moved Permanently, StatusCode=301]

Tags: apex, rest-api, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, sharepoint

I am trying to upload a doc from salesforce to Sharepoint. Below code i am executing in developer console.i am getting error as below

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Moved Permanently, StatusCode=301]

Code - for access token

```
String clientId = 'db12000f-<redacted>'; 
String clientSecret = '0llSL19n9<redacted>';
String tenantId = 'eca5bad8-<redacted>';
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
//https://login.microsoftonline.com/< tenant Id>/oauth2/token
req.setEndpoint('https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/'+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(tenantId, 'UTF-8').replaceAll('\\+', '%20')+'/oauth2/token'); 
String body = 'grant_type=client_credentials'+
    '&client_id=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(clientId, 'UTF-8') +
    '&client_secret='+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(clientSecret, 'UTF-8') +
    '&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com';                              
req.setBody(body);
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
String s = res.getBody();
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);
System.debug('Response Body: ' + m);
```

Code for getting folder details

```
 String access_token= String.valueof(m.get('access_token'));
    String folderUrl = '/documents/SidFirstFolder';
    Http h1 = new Http();
    HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
    req1.setMethod('GET');
    req1.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ access_token);
    req1.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req1.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    req1.setEndpoint('http://learningsfdc.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('+folderUrl+')?$expand=Folders,Files');
    HttpResponse res1 = h1.send(req1);
    System.debug('Response Body: ' + res1);
```

Comment: Just like passwords, you should never post things like `clientSecret` publicly. It allows other people to use your credentials. I've removed them from your question, but you should consider them compromised and have them changed immediately.

Comment: apologies.. thanks..

Answer (score 3):

301 is **not** an error. It's a redirect. What you need to do is read the response headers for the Location header, and provide all the other original headers and cookies, if provided by the HttpResponse header.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox - i didnt understand location header...my endpoint in the debug log looks like this..System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=http://learningsfdc.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(/documents/SidFirstFolder)?$expand=Folders,Files, Method=GET] and response body - Response Body: System.HttpResponse[Status=Moved Permanently, StatusCode=301]

Comment: @learningmode I believe what sfdcfox is getting at is that you need to look at `res1.getHeaderKeys()` and `res1.getHeader()`. One of your header keys should be `Location`, and that should tell you where your request actually needs to go to (where the server is telling you to redirect your request to). It could simply be that you sent a request to an http endpoint instead of an https one.

Comment: in res1.getHeaderKeys() i am getting - (Connection, Content-Length, Date, Content-Type) and in res1.getHeader() if i iterate i am getting - close, 311, Sun, 04 Aug 2019 17:28:56 GMT, text/html; charset=us-ascii. I m not getting any location